# Theme is not Matched in Android

Tags: android

I am using Theme.holo for my layout . For this reason , I have the following layout :

[image]

But in my device , The layout is as the following :

[image]

Why have I got the totally different layout in my device ?

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblNID"
                style="@style/FieldLabelTextStyle"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/NID" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/textNID"
                style="@style/FieldInputTextStyle"
                android:inputType="text" >
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblMSISDN"
                style="@style/FieldLabelTextStyle"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/msisdn" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/textFathersName"
                style="@style/FieldInputTextStyle"
                android:inputType="text" >
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblBirthDate"
                style="@style/FieldLabelTextStyle"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/dob" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/dateFieldDay"
                    style="@style/FieldInputTextStyle"
                    android:hint="day"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" >
                </EditText>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="/"
                    android:textSize="24dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/dateFieldMonth"
                    style="@style/FieldInputTextStyle"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:hint="month"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" >
                </EditText>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="/"
                    android:textSize="24dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/dateFieldYear"
                    style="@style/FieldInputTextStyle"
                    android:hint="year"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="4" >
                </EditText>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblRE_MSISDN"
                style="@style/FieldLabelTextStyle"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/re_msisdn" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/textRE_MSISDN"
                style="@style/FieldInputTextStyle"
                android:inputType="text" >
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblRE_CODE"
                style="@style/FieldLabelTextStyle"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/re_code" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/RE_CODEField"
                style="@style/FieldInputTextStyle" 
                android:inputType="text" >
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout  
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout9"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_weight="1" >
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/grabDataButtonId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="GREAB Finger Print Data"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancelButtonId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

        android:text="SEND REQUEST"
        android:layout_weight="1"
          />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Check your device `API Version`

Comment: How can I check that ?

Comment: Can you show me your styles.xml. . and manifest

Comment: Also check `Activity Theme` added in `values-11` and `values-14` folder in `style.xml`

Comment: Menifest files link is http://codepaste.net/uy6rzu

Comment: Styles.xml link is :http://codepaste.net/yd6kaq

Comment: So it's 21, how about the styles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your Appmanifest, Declare the theme there see if it works.

> application android:name=PACKAGE NAME
>
> ```
>     android:largeHeap="true"
>     android:allowBackup="true"
>     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
> ```